# How can I match double-quoted strings with escaped double-quote characters?

Tags: regex, perl, escaping

I need a Perl regular expression to match a string. I'm assuming only double-quoted strings, that a \" is a literal quote character and NOT the end of the string, and that a \ is a literal backslash character and should not escape a quote character. If it's not clear, some examples:

```
"\""    # string is 1 character long, contains dobule quote
"\\"    # string is 1 character long, contains backslash
"\\\""  # string is 2 characters long, contains backslash and double quote
"\\\\"  # string is 2 characters long, contains two backslashes
```

I need a regular expression that can recognize all 4 of these possibilities, and all other simple variations on those possibilities, as valid strings. What I have now is:

```
/".*[^\\]"/
```

But that's not right - it won't match any of those except the first one. Can anyone give me a push in the right direction on how to handle this?

Comment: Can you even do this regex?  I think you'd need a state machine.

Comment: Regexps can do pretty much everything that doesn't require recursion (though even that can be tackled in modern Perl versions using some really hairy code).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How about this?

```
/"([^\\"]|\\\\|\\")*"/
```

matches zero or more characters that aren't slashes or quotes OR two slashes OR a slash then a quote

Comment: Paul: strings can be matched by regexes, however parenthesised expressions (and anything else that can nest arbitrarily deep) cannot.

Comment: This regex has false positives on strings such as """

Comment: Cal: I think you need to double all of those backslashes.  (Maybe you already did, and SO stripped them out?)

Comment: It looks fine to me. In some languages double slashed are necessary, but not in Perl.

Comment: fyi, i did double the backslashes and SO stripped them

Comment: You need to "code-ify" the regex:  either enclose it in `backticks`, or indent it four spaces and leave empty lines above and below it.

Comment: @Cal: yes, that's happened to me too.  The `backticks` cures that, as Alan suggested.

Comment: @Leon: By coincidence, Cal's original regex **as displayed** (i.e. with no doubled backslashes) was *also* valid Perl syntax, although it didn't do what he wanted -- e.g. it let through """ as you pointed out.  The double-backslashed version now on display doesn't have that problem.

Comment: WARNING there is an insane silent failure with this regex if the string is >32k/64k due to a Perl bug from 2002 that has not yet been fixed in 2020!!! https://stackoverflow.com/a/26229500/1046167

Answer (score 44):

`/"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*"/`

This is almost the same as Cal's answer, but has the advantage of matching strings containing escape codes such as `\n`.

The `?:` characters are there to prevent the contained expression being saved as a backreference, but they can be removed.

**NOTE:** as pointed out by Louis Semprini, this is limited to 32kb texts due a recursion limit built into Perl's regex engine (that unfortunately silently returns a failure when hit, instead of crashing loudly).

Comment: This answer is more correct. I tested a lot more strings and it works better than @Cal's for things like `"\"\'\""`.

Comment: WARNING there is an insane silent failure with this regex if the string is >32k/64k due to a Perl bug from 2002 that has not yet been fixed in 2020!!! https://stackoverflow.com/a/26229500/1046167

Comment: @LouisSemprini: Surprising, thanks! The reason (stack growth due to backtracking) is arguably sensible, at least for a backtracking RE implementation ([most REs can be actually searched for without backtracking using DFA-based algorithm instead](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html)), but I think this should definitely `die()` with a visible error.

Answer (score 9):

A generic solution(matching all backslashed characters):

```
/ \A "               # Start of string and opening quote
  (?:                #  Start group
    [^\\"]           #   Anything but a backslash or a quote
    |                #  or
    \\.              #   Backslash and anything
  )*                 # End of group
  " \z               # Closing quote and end of string
  /xms
```

Comment: Though you may want to omit the `\A` and/or `\z` -- they imply that there can be nothing preceding or trailing the double-quoted string.

Answer (score 5):

See [Text::Balanced](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Balanced/). It's better than reinvent wheel. Use `gen_delimited_pat` to see result pattern and learn form it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a very simple way:

```
/"(?:\\?.)*?"/
```

Just remember if you're embedding such a regex in a string to double the backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

[RegExp::Common](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp::Common) is another useful tool to be aware of.  It contains regexps for many common cases, included quoted strings:

```
use Regexp::Common;

my $str = '" this is a \" quoted string"';
if ($str =~ $RE{quoted}) {
  # do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code :  `(\".+")`