# RegEx to match only character constants and specific escape sequences

Tags: c, regex, bison, flex-lexer

I'm trying to match a character constant. I only want single characters and a few escape sequences rather than \ followed by any letter.

This is very similar to this question with the added requirement of specific escape characters.
[Regular expression to match escaped characters (quotes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525556/regular-expression-to-match-escaped-characters-quotes)

```
'(\\\[tvrnafb\\\]|.)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel dumb, I just had to remove the period in the other answer and add another character class.

```
'(\\[tvrnafb\\]|[^\\'])'
```