# How to make a Regex on Interpolated Strings

Tags: c#, regex

c# has [Interpolated strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/dn961160.aspx). This means that this string:

```
"{Variable} Text \{NotVariable\}"
```

corresponds to:

```
Variable + "Text {NotVariable}"
```

I need to check, that the string is allowed AND spil in into a list of the inputs, eg. Variable and "Text {NotVaraible}".

A guy posted a similar question, but I can't modify the answer to suit my need.
[Link to similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525556/regular-expression-to-match-escaped-characters-quotes)

Does anyone have a propper solution?

Comment: You mean you have to process some literal `"{Variable} \"Text \{NotVariable\}\""`?

Comment: I need to convert the string "{Variable} Text \{NotVariable\}" into two different strings.

Comment: Well, there is something unclear: escaping the `{` and `}` in interpolated strings means doubling them. So, the example should read `$"{Variable} \"Text\" {{NotVariable}}"`, and you need to turn that into `Variable + "\"Text\" {{NotVariable}}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the [following regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fs)(%3F%3Cbndr%3E%5C%24%22%7C(%3F!%5E)%5CG)%0D%0A(%3F%3A%0D%0A%20(%3F%3Cvar%3E%7B%5B%5E%7D%5D*%7D)%20%0D%0A%20%7C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20(%3F%3Cliteral%3E(%3F%3A%5C%5C.%7C%7B%7B%7C%7D%7D%7C%5B%5E%22%5C%5C%7B%7D%5D)*)%0D%0A)&i=%24%22text1%20%7BVariable%7D%20%5C%22Text%5C%22%20%7B%7BNotVariable%7D%7D%22&o=x):

```
(?s)(?<bndr>\$"|(?!^)\G)     # Get the start of the interpolated string literal or the end of previous match
(?:
 (?<var>{[^}]*})             # Match a variable {non-braces-inside}
 |                           # OR...
 (?<literal>(?:\\.|{{|}}|[^"\\{}])*) # Escaped entities or everything else
)
```

See this C# demo results:

```
var Variable = "";
var input_text = "$\"text1 {Variable} \\\"Text\\\" {{NotVariable}}\"";
var pat = @"(?s)(?<bndr>\$""|(?!^)\G)(?:(?<var>{[^}]*})|(?<literal>(?:\\.|{{|}}|[^""\\{}])*))";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input_text, pat)
     .Cast<Match>()
     .Select(p => p.Groups["var"].Success ? p.Groups["var"].Value.Trim(' ', '{', '}') : "\"" + p.Groups["literal"].Value.Replace("{{", "{").Replace("}}", "}") + "\"")
     .ToList();
matches.RemoveAll(p => p == "\"\"");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" + ", matches));                             //"text1 " + Variable + " \"Text\" {NotVariable}"
var result_string = "text1 " + Variable + " \"Text\" {NotVariable}" + "";   //text1  "Text" {NotVariable}
var check_string = $"text1 {Variable} \"Text\" {{NotVariable}}";            //text1  "Text" {NotVariable}
```

The `result_string` that is built from the output of joined `matches`  and `check_string` (actual interpolated string) are equal.