# Python regex match anything enclosed in either quotations brackets braces or parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

## UPDATE

> This is still not entirely the solution so far. It is only for preceding repeated closing characters (e.g `))`, `]]`, `}}`). I'm still looking for a way to capture enclosed contents and will update this.

Code:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'(\(.+?[?<!)]\))', '((x(y)z))', re.DOTALL).groups()
('((x(y)z))',)
```

Details:

```
r'(\(.+?[?<!)]\))'
```

- `()` - Capturing group special characters.
- `\(` and `\)` - The open and closing characters (e.g `'`, `"`, `()`, `{}`, `[]`)
- `.+?` - Match *any* character content (use with `re.DOTALL` flag)
- `[?<!)]` - The negative lookbehind for character `)` (replace this with the matching closing character). This will basically find any `)` character where `\)` character does not precede (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973495/8555967)).

---

<s>I was trying to parse something like a variable assignment statement for this lexer thing I'm working with, just trying to get the basic logic behind interpreters/compilers.</s>

Here's the basic assignment statements and literals I'm dealing with:

```
az = none
az_ = true
az09 = false
az09_ = +0.9
az_09 = 'az09_'
_az09 = "az09_"
_az = [
  "az",
  0.9
]
_09 = {
  0: az
  1: 0.9
}
_ = (
  true
)
```

<s>Somehow, I managed to parse those simple assignments like `none`, `true`, `false`, and numeric literals. Here's where I'm currently stuck at:</s>

```
import sys
import re

# validate command-line arguments
if (len(sys.argv) != 2): raise ValueError('usage: parse <script>')

# parse the variable name and its value
def handle_assignment(index, source):
    # TODO: handle quotations, brackets, braces, and parenthesis values
    variable = re.search(r'[\S\D]([\w]+)\s+?=\s+?(none|true|false|[-+]?\d+\.?\d+|[\'\"].*[\'\"])', source[index:])
    if variable is not None:
        print('{}={}'.format(variable.group(1), variable.group(2)))
        index += source[index:].index(variable.group(2))
    return index

# parse through the source element by element
with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
    source = file.read()
    index = 0
    while index < len(source):
        # checks if the line matches a variable assignment statement
        if re.match(r'[\S\D][\w]+\s+?=', source[index:]):
            index = handle_assignment(index, source)
        index += 1
```

<s>I was looking for a way to capture those values with enclosed quotations, brackets, braces, and parenthesis.</s>

Probably, will update this post if I found an answer.

Comment: Can there be nested brackets e.g. `(words (and some more words))`?

Comment: @Nick Whatever content there is. I just need the whole thing that enclosed with these characters: `'`, `"`, `()`, `[]`, or `{}`

Comment: You could use a parser instead.

Comment: @Jan I found the answer. I'm editing my post right now so others could benefit from it.

Comment: @Jan Was trying to implement my own parser to understand the logic...

Comment: Please, don't add answer in question. Post it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I will add my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regexp with multiple alternatives for each matching pair.

```
re.match(r'\'.*?\'|".*?"|\(.*?\)|\[.*?\]|\{.*?\}', s)
```

Note, however, that if there are nested brackets, this will match the first ending bracket, e.g. if the input is

```
(words (and some more words))
```

the result will be

```
(words (and some more words)
```

Regular expressions are not appropriate for matching nested structures, you should use a more powerful parsing technique.

Comment: I was thinking if it's possible to just create a set for both the open and closing characters and just _anything_ in the middle? Something like: `r"[\'\"\[\{\(]ANYTHING[\'\"\]\}\)]"`

Comment: That will not necessarily match the corresponding end bracket for a starting bracket. So it could match `'XXX)`

Comment: I think a simple `.*` instead of `.*?` for each pattern is what you would want? Am I missing something?

Comment: If you use a greedy regexp, it can match too much. if the string is `'foo' (abc) 'bar'` the first alternative will match the entire thing instead of just `'foo'`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for @Barmar's recursive characters using the [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) third-party module:

```
pip install regex
```

```
python3
>>> import regex
>>> recurParentheses = regex.compile(r'[(](?:[^()]|(?R))*[)]')
>>> recurParentheses.findall('(z(x(y)z)x) ((x)(y)(z))')
['(z(x(y)z)x)', '((x)(y)(z))']
>>> recurCurlyBraces = regex.compile(r'[{](?:[^{}]|(?R))*[}]')
>>> recurCurlyBraces.findall('{z{x{y}z}x} {{x}{y}{z}}')
['{z{x{y}z}x}', '{{x}{y}{z}}']
>>> recurSquareBrackets = regex.compile(r'[[](?:[^][]|(?R))*[]]')
>>> recurSquareBrackets.findall('[z[x[y]z]x] [[x][y][z]]')
['[z[x[y]z]x]', '[[x][y][z]]']
```

For string literal recursion, I suggest take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6525556/8555967).

Comment: This only matches `()`, can you expand it to handle all the different bracketing pairs?

Comment: @Barmar Yes. All you have to do is replace the escaped characters: `\(`, `\)`, as well as the the matching characters within the set: `[^()]`. Here's another example: `regex.findall(r'(\{(?>[^{}]+|(?R))*\})', '{z{x{y}z}x} {{x}{y}{z}}')`